# Methods with receivers of pointer type won't list in reflection

Tags: go

I was trying to generalize my code by using reflection to call all methods of a type. It's easy and straightforward but there is a problem with that, reflection.TypeOf(T).NumMethods (or other methods) ignores methods which used receiver type as a pointer.
For example this small code will print 1 instead of 2:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Foo struct {}

func (f Foo) Bar() {}

func (f *Foo) Baz() {}

func main() {
    obj := Foo{}
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(obj).NumMethod())
}
```

You can run in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NyrkvRZjV_B).
It prints 1 because of Bar method. If you delete the pointer (*) from Baz, it will print 2.

My question is how can I list all methods regardless of receiver type.

Thanks

Comment: Because the type you're passing to `TypeOf` isn't a pointer. It gives you the type for the argument you pass in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the pointer of `obj` to get all Methods:

```
func main() {
    obj := &Foo{}
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(obj).NumMethod())
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/MOe9-oQzkHV)

Answer (score 1):

Get pointer to method with pointer type receiver. In case you wants to call the method by name using reflection here is the code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Foo struct{}

func (f Foo) Bar() {
    fmt.Println("Inside Bar")
}

func (f *Foo) Baz() {
    fmt.Println("Inside Baz")
}

func main() {
    rfl := reflect.ValueOf(&Foo{})
    v := rfl.MethodByName("Baz")

    results := v.Call(nil)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", results)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(&Foo{}).NumMethod())
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lErBTyYD3W-)